# Issues Uploading file Node & React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post

In my project, I am simply trying to **upload a file to my Node server from my React frontend.** It is a simple post to the server that I am using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for, but it appears that the data is either not being sent or is not able to be interpreted. I am also attempting to use [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) as a solution, but it does not seem to be solving the issue. Here are the code snippets:

**React (App.js)**

```
var URLs = {
   imgUpload: 'http://127.0.0.1:8003/imgUpload'
};

class App extends Component {

  ...

  uploadHandler = () => {

    console.log('handling upload...')
    if (this.state.activeFile == null) {
      alert('Please Select an Image!!');
    } else {
    let af = this.state.activeFile;
    console.log('active file: ' + JSON.stringify(af))

    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', af);
    data.append('name', af.name);
    console.log('attempting to post: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
    axios.post(URLs.imgUpload, data, {
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    }
)
    }
  }

  addFile = (event: any): void => {
    let activeFile = event.target.files[0];
      console.log('Added file ' + activeFile);
      this.setState ({
        activeFile: activeFile,
      });
  }

render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">

   ...

   <FormGroup>
       <ControlLabel htmlFor="fileUpload" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}><h3><Label bsStyle="success">Add file</Label></h3>
           <FormControl
            id="fileUpload"
            type="file"
        //    accept=".pdf"
            onChange={this.addFile}
            style={{ display: "none" }}
        />

           <Button bsStyle="success" onClick={this.uploadHandler}>Upload</Button>
       </ControlLabel>
   </FormGroup>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

**Node:**

```
 const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
 var express = require('express')
 var app = express();



app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
 ...

 app.post('/imgUpload', function(req, res) {
     let img = req;
     console.log('attempting to upload image, searching for data...')
     console.log('Files: ' + req.files)
     var body = "";
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;

            // 1e6 === 1 * Math.pow(10, 6) === 1 * 1000000 ~~~ 1MB
            if (body.length > 1e6) {
                // FLOOD ATTACK OR FAULTY CLIENT, NUKE REQUEST
                req.connection.destroy();
            }
        });

 });
```

The website console:

[image]

The node console:

```
attempting to upload image, searching for data...
Files: undefined
```

Comment: try setting the content type like `headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }`

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I updated the NodeJS code, is that what you meant?

Comment: No. Set content type in post request like `axios.post(URL, data, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data`
  }
})`

Comment: I made the change and updated the question to include it, but it still shows undefined for the files

Comment: @GeorgeBailey do you have an idea as to why `activeFile` is empty?

Comment: That seems like it might be the issue

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1006#issuecomment-320165427